# Raspberry Pi: Can I turn on a monitor over HDMI?

Tags: raspberry-pi, monitor, raspbian, hdmi

I have a Model A Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. It is connected to a small monitor by HDMI (the monitor model: FEELWORLD FW819HAT).

I'm currently working on making something similar to a digital picture frame, and I would like the monitor to automatically turn on and begin displaying pictures as soon as my Pi boots up. Right now, after plugging everything in I still have to press a button on the monitor for it to display anything. Therefore I was hoping to I could send a signal from the Pi over the HDMI that would force the monitor to turn on.

So far my research has turned up tvservice as one way to turn on and off a monitor connected to the Pi. This is the command I've used to try turning the monitor on:

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p
```

This doesn't work the way I want it to. When I *already* have turned the monitor on once, I can turn it off and on again with tvservice, but on boot up (before I've pressed the monitor's on-switch) the same commands seem to do nothing.

Where am I going wrong? Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Maybe use a display that allows HDMI Control?

Comment: Is that the same thing as CEC? And is there a way find out if my display has that through the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *if* your monitor supports HDMI CEC (not all do). If so, you can use [`libcec`](http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/) to send a power signal.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15749

Comment: Thanks! This definitely seems like the right approach. I ended up installing libcec / cec-client, but unfortunately discovered that my monitor does not support HDMI CEC. :( Sadly, this was not mentioned anywhere in documentation about the device.

Comment: How can we know if the monitor support CEC? I tried to check several brands and type like LG, ASUS, and the like (through amazon) and they do not mention the word CEC on the specs.